# How to enforce user to change passwd after Password Expiration timeout in Android 3.0?

Tags: android, passwords

I was trying to use Android Password expiration feature using
`DeviceAdmin`. When I call `setPasswordExpirationTimeout()` API , it only
sends a notification and doesn't actually force the user to change the
password. It only sends a notification after timeout:

> V/DevicePolicyManagerService(  662): Sending password expiration
>   notifications for action
>   com.android.server.ACTION_EXPIRED_PASSWORD_NOTIFICATION
>
> You have to get the callback in DeviceAdminReceiver in
>   onPasswordExpired() to force user to change password.

Any specific reason it's been implemented this way (or is it just to
give flexibility to the programmer)?

The only option I could see is starting activity with intent `ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD` in the callback in `DeviceAdminReceiver` which the user can overrule by simply pressing 'Cancel' button.

How to 100% enforce the to change password ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the [DeviceAdminSample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html#Misc) ([source code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.html))?  The Android SDK comes with all the samples so you can easily add the ApiDemos as an Eclipse project and run it in the simulator.

I originally thought you could call the [resetPassword](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#resetPassword%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method in the [DevicePolicyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html), but you would need the user to have given you their new password to do that, which I assume you don't want to do!

Comment: found something relevant over here: https://github.com/sindhureddy2903/Android-Security-Alert-Application/blob/77c8a19a95c6e2607b1338b612df3a16b628f148/androidsecurity/androidsecurity/app/src/main/java/edu/ucdenver/androidsecurity/DevicePolicyAdmin.java